# Use WampServer's MySQL as a real MySQL for going on the net

Tags: mysql, apache, tomcat, wampserver

Is this a right thing to do? I am using the Apache/Tomcat that comes with the liferay portal bundle and I used the MySQL that comes with WampServer at home but now I want to transfer my portal to a real Server and I wanted to know whether I could still use the Wamp's MySQL or should I install a real MySQL (What's the difference?)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAMPS MySQL server is not artificial, its the real deal. WAMP just bundles these softwares together and lets you deploy easily for development purposes. In a production environment you would deploy MySQL as a separate software and tweak it according to your needs. You CAN you WAMP on production environment, however you will need to make sure that you do not have any security flaws in there.